# What is the point of having both Servlet Filters and AuthenticationProviders in Spring Security?

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, authorization, servlet-filters

I'm somewhat confused after reading the documentation...it seems you can do a complete authentication with either mechanism without using the other. You can get access to the request in an AuthenticationProvider and you can set the security context in a servlet filter. So why have both?

Comment: Don't use servlet filters for authentication. There are dedicated hooks in the relevant frameworks for that e.g. Spring Security or valves in Tomcat

Comment: @DavidBrossard but...why? Spring Security documentation seems to suggest this is a valid approach. I just read a book utilizing this approach (Full-Stack Dev with Spring Boot 2.0 and React) and have seen multiple tutorials doing the same. There are clearly other ways to go besides filters (i.e. AuthenticationProvider)...but my question is, why bother?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can perform any (custom) authentication and authorization within a filter of a servlet based web application if you choose to do so.

**However, spring-security is not only meant for servlet based web applications.**

An `AuthenticationProvider` implementation can be used for authentication by many different filters of servlet based web applications but also by e.g. socket-based network applications and even by native non-web applications and is generally totally agnostic to the communication protocol your app is relying on.

By implementing your custom `AuthenticationProvider` interface you are following the separation-of-concerns principle and you will later be able to delegate to it from different filters if necessary or from other code parts without duplicating your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is a kind of clean code design. `AuthenticationProvider` and its related objects are more general model which has nothing to depend on the infrastructure related things such as `Servlet`.

It is similar to what the domain model described in [domain-driven-design](/questions/tagged/domain-driven-design). By separating the infrastructure concern from the actual domain models, we can reuse that same domain model (i.e codes) in other infrastructure environments such as using it in an standalone desktop application or in the reactive web application which you do not have the concept likes Servlet Filter at there.

You can think that the Servlet Filter is a sort of infrastructure codes that bind two worlds together. (Servlet world and spring security domain model world).